# Dropdown in angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-directives, angular7, angular4-forms

I have a drop down menu where the disabled text select from below is the text that appears on the dropdown button, when this button is clicked the list of choices are displayed. But when the list of choices are displayed and a tick mark appears preceding the first choice, even before any choice is selected. Could some one explain why and how to get rid of the tick mark from the first choice?

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="selectedChoiceIndex"(ngModelChange)="onSwitchChoice($event)">
  <option value="-1" disabled selected hidden>{{<select from below> }}</option>
  <option *ngFor="let choice of choices; let i = index" [value]="i" >{{choice}}</option>
</select>
```

Actual result:

```
<select from below>
> choice1(please assume this symbol > as a tick mark)
choice2
choice3
```

Desired result:

```
<select from below>
choice1
choice2
choice3
```

There should be no tick mark preceding any choice unless selected.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have the solution but I need to verify, can you show the TS code so I can see what is going on with your `ngModel` **or better yet** can you create a [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular)?

Comment: @Phix Thanks it works

Comment: What is `selectedChoiceIndex` set to? Are you setting this to `0` ? Why is the first selection `hidden` ?

Comment: @Igor It is set to -1, I think the problem here is because of hidden

Comment: All hidden does is hide the `<Select From Below>` option when you've selected one of the actual options, I'm not sure I understand how that fixes your issue.

Comment: What about changing the first option to `[value]="-1"` so it is assigned the integer -1 instead of the string "-1".